# Android XML cutting off bottom half of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-xml

I have a problem with my XML layout, something that I thought wouldn't give me many problems. I have a layout below in a scroll view, but **the bottom of the layout is being cut off**, I can't see anything past the second list view. From looking around, I can't seem to see anything wrong with the xml itself and I can't see what I am doing wrong.

I have tried the suggestion to the problem, that is adding a weight to each of the different elements but this still hasnt solved the problem.

I have also added the main activity in which the fragment is placed incase that might help solve the problem

**Fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Recipe Title"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ingredientsHeading"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Ingredients"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ingredientsList"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ingredientsHeading"
            android:layout_above="@+id/directionsHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="195dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>

        <Button style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Add Ingredient"
            android:id="@+id/addIngredient"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ingredientsList"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/directionsHeading"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addIngredient"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Directions"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/directionsList"
            android:layout_below="@+id/directionsHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="195dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>

        <Button style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Add Direction"
            android:id="@+id/addDirection"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ingredientsList"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/filterButton"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/floatingButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Main XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout2">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.rory.pocketchef.Fragments.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: please post a screenshot...

Comment: you should not use nested weights. Android studio must have warned you about it and also weight can never be more than weightsum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the issue. As the scroll view was being displayed the bottom was being cut off by the bottom action bar on the actual phone. So to solve this I added padding to the bottom of the scrollview in order to push it back up above the action bar.

The new layout it as follows

**Updated working XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"> <<<-------added this line
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Recipe Title"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ingredientsHeading"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Ingredients"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ingredientsList"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ingredientsHeading"
            android:layout_above="@+id/directionsHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="195dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>

        <Button style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Add Ingredient"
            android:id="@+id/addIngredient"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ingredientsList"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/directionsHeading"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addIngredient"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Directions"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/directionsList"
            android:layout_below="@+id/directionsHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="195dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>

        <Button style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Add Direction"
            android:id="@+id/addDirection"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ingredientsList"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addDirection">

            <Button style="@style/Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Add Direction"
                android:id="@+id/showOptionsDialog"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button style="@style/Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Add Direction"
                android:id="@+id/saveRecipe"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/showOptionsDialog"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/filterButton"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/floatingButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It will Give two much padding from bottom, rather we can have a invisible view at the bottom of the main xml of height  2dp and tell scrollview to be above that view. Then also this issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

**use weightSum for all components in your xml file**,

It's `android:layout_weight`. Weight can only be used in LinearLayout. If the orientation of linearlayout is **Vertical**, then use `android:layout_height="0dp"` and if the orientation is **horizontal**, then use **android:layout_width = "0d**p". It'll work perfectly.

> From your question -- bottom of the layout is being cut off

It is because of fixed height given to components.

### EDIT -- xml added

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Recipe Title" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ingredientsHeading"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Ingredients"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/ingredientsList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addIngredient"
                    style="@style/AppTheme"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:text="Add Ingredient" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/directionsHeading"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Directions"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/directionsList"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addDirection"
                    style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:text="Add Direction" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: should I be changing the android:layout_height for all the elements of the XML?

Comment: yes, if you change xml according to android:layout_weight than change height of all components.

Comment: here you have given fixed hight so it will not be displayed to whole screen.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but no it is not I am still having the same issue, would it be too much to ask for you to redo my XML? I just cannot seem to get it right at all

Comment: please check my edited answer. just copy that to your layout, i have done it all @JJSmith

Comment: Thank you for the XML but this is still giving the same error but no I cannot scroll at all and the layout doesn't scroll at all as opposed to the small bit it used to

Comment: do you have data in listview ?

Comment: Nope no data at the moment but I will have data in the list soon

Comment: please show some support to answers, upvote or accept answer if your issue solved

Comment: My issue still isnt solved, I will accept once I find  solution however

Answer (score 4):

Add these lines in your ScrollView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"

android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: make scrollview your layouts parrent  like below code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@drawable/edittextborder"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >


    </LinearLayout>

   


</ScrollView>

Answer (score 2):

You put a `weightsum` of 1 and your `scrollview` is 28. You have to put something like that `<LinearLayout weightsum=15>`(you don't have to put 15) and then what is inside your layout you have to distribute your 15 sum. Like `<TextView layout_weight=1>` it means that your `textview` is gonna 1/15. When I use weight I also put the height or the width, depending on which one I want to play, to 0dp. For exemple if I want to play on the width `<TextView width=0dp height=wrap_content weight=1>`. So you have to give a weight to every child of your `LinearLayout`.
Hope it help.

Edit: Also ListView in a ScrollView is not a good idea, could come from here. Look this post:
[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

Comment: add these lines in your scrollview